# how do i get the attribute value with comparing another attribute?

Tags: jquery

```
<tbody>
<tr class="taskEditRow" rowid="1" level="0" taskid="-1" __template="TASKROW">
<tr class="taskEditRow" rowid="2" level="1" taskid="-2" __template="TASKROW">
<tr class="taskEditRow" rowid="3" level="2" taskid="-3" __template="TASKROW">
<tr class="taskEditRow" rowid="4" level="2" taskid="-4" __template="TASKROW">
</tbody>
```

here i want to get the rowid with comparing task id using jquery

```
var x=$(".taskEditRow").attr("taskid==-1");

var y=x.attr("rowid");
```

like i want rowid with comparing of taskid

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowId = $('.taskEditRow[taskid="-1"]').attr("rowid");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $(".taskEditRow[taskid='-1']");
var y = x.attr("rowid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that:

```
var x=$(".taskEditRow[taskid=-1]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
var x = $(".taskEditRow[taskid='-1']");
var y = x.attr("rowid");
```

Comment: hi if i will print y it says undefined i want rowid

Comment: Run the selectors in your browser console and check whether you're really able to select the row with above selector.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying, since none of the answers are doing.

You need to use the [Attribute Equals Selector (`[attr="value"]`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). For example,

```
var $row  = $('.taskEditRow[taskid="-1"]');
var rowid = $row.attr("rowid");
```

Or, you can also make use of a `.filter()`.

```
var $row  = $('.taskEditRow').filter(function(){
  return this.getAttribute("taskid") == "-1";
});
var rowid = $row.attr("rowid");
```

Comment: if i print the rowid it says undefined

Comment: @user1957952, is that your HTML? If it is, then it is invalid. [It should like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Dt63V/)

Comment: thank u i got output but i change rowid to task id                                                                var $row  = $('.taskEditRow').filter(function(){
  return this.getAttribute("taskid") == "-1";
});
var rowid = $row.attr("rowid");